# Using the same connection (NATS) within a service

Tags: c#, connection, using

I have a service which will publish messages to NATS on two different occasions - on entity created and on entity updated.

In the official NATS tutorial, the publisher always creates a new connection and inside the using block it publishes the message and flushes the connections, e.g:

```
using (IEncodedConnection connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateEncodedConnection(options))
{
    c.OnSerialize = jsonSerializer;
    connection.Publish(subject, payload);
    connection.Flush();
}
```

However reading about this and from my own prespective I really need only one connection which I can reuse throughout the life of my service. Implementing this seems like a trivial work:

```
public class EncodedConnection
{
    private static IEncodedConnection encodedConnection;
    
    private EncodedConnection()
    {

    }
    
    public static IEncodedConnection GetEncodedConnection()
    {
        if (encodedConnection != null)
        {
            return encodedConnection;
        }

        encodedConnection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateEncodedConnection();
        encodedConnection.OnSerialize = jsonSerializer;
        
        return encodedConnection;
    }
}
```

My questions are

- since I don't provide a using block for the connection is it safe to pass it around like this.
- Also should I call `connection.Flush();` everytime i publish a message and if I call flush do I need to create new connection which basically means that I have to create a new connection everytime nevertheless.